# Unauthorized error when uploading task to TFS

Tags: tfs

I have TFS 2015 Update 3 installed in my Windows 10 laptop and I am trying to upload a custom task to TFS. I have installed Node.js and tfs-cli but when I try to upload my task using my logon credentials I get an 401 Unauthorized error.

The command I am using is

```
tfx build tasks upload –-task-path ./MyTask --auth-type basic
--username <user> --password <password> 
--service-url http://localhost:8080/tfs/defaultcollection
```

I have enabled basic authentication for TFS as suggested in other posts TFS but this does not seem to made any difference,

The error I get is

```
TFS Cross Platform Command Line Interface v0.4.5
Copyright Microsoft Corporation
error: Error: Failed Request: Unauthorized(401) - http://localhost:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/_apis/distributedtask
```

My user is configured to have 'Advanced' access level with TFS but is there an additional right I need to add? Looking on other posts the command above looks to work with TFS2017 but I can't get it to work on TFS 2015.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For 401 error, first please double check if you have correctly enable Basic Authentication following this [tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli/blob/master/docs/configureBasicAuth.md).

Then try to login before issuing commands when using tfx against your TFS server.

Type the following login command:

```
tfx login --auth-type basic
```

1. You will be prompted to add your service url.
2. You will be prompted for your username. Use **`domain\user`** (e.g.
   fabrikam\peter). If you are working on a workgroup machine, use
   **`machinename\user`**.

   You will be prompted for your password. Enter the password for the username you entered.

You can now use any other tfx command.

```
> tfx login --auth-type basic
Copyright Microsoft Corporation

Enter service url > http://localhost:8080/tfs/defaultcollection
Enter username > fabfiber\peter
Enter password > *******
logged in successfully
```

More details please refer: [Use the TFS Cross Platform Command Line with TFS using basic authentication](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/auth/tfs-basic-auth)

> Besides, you need to be in the top level **Agent Pool Administrators
>   group** to manipulate tasks See [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/agents) for permissions requirement.